# Add Extra info like Data attribute or id in heat map highcharts jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have one requirement in heat map Highcharts.
On click of each cell i want some info.

I tried below code:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    var str = event.point.series.yAxis.categories[event.point.y] + ',' +
                event.point.series.xAxis.categories[event.point.x]
                    alert(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will give me x-axis and y-axis value.

But I wanted to add id or data attribute to each cell so that on click i will get that particular value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Link:https://jsfiddle.net/1f7L8u25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more information by using custom attributes. Like this:

```
series: [{
  x: 0, y: 0, value: 10, customAttrib: 'Text here', customNumber:  154},
  x: 0, y: 1, value: 19, customAttrib: 'Text here', customNumber:  141},
  ...
]}
```

And then you reference that field by:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      click: function (event) {
        var str = event.point.series.yAxis.categories[event.point.y] + ',' + event.point.series.xAxis.categories[event.point.x] + ',' + event.point.customAttrib + ',' + event.point.customNumber
        alert(str);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Here is a working example (click on Alexander, Monday or Tuesday) :** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/1f7L8u25/3/